# Newbie : Save User Credentials in Salesforce

Tags: apex, visualforce, app-development, database

I am making an App which has to run in Salesforce and eventually distributed over Appexchange. In my app, I would like the Salesforce user to enter his Username and Password (with which he registered on my website). I would like to save these credentials in Salesforce. Once the credentials have been verified, my Salesforce can simply fetch user data from my website and show it in Salesforce and enable the user to edit it through Salesforce.

Can anybody tell me a right strategy for storing the username and password. Can I associate a db with my app and save these over there. Also I am new to Salesforce platform and hence I studied Salesforce Point and click app and basics of Apex and Visualforce. I am a Java developer and would I need to go through any other things apart from these.

According to my understanding till now, I create a data model for my app using Point and click features (creating Custom objects and fields). Then I implement my business logic in Apex (logging to my website and fetching data from my website) and I would be using Visualforce for UI. Please confirm that my understanding is correct as well.

Thank you
Abhinav

Comment: Rather than storing credentials in SF, have you considered SF as identity provider ?

Comment: Hi Sdry. Can you elaborate a little more on what you are trying to say? To access the data at my website via HTTP APIs, we will need a session token. This session token is generated only after the user sends login credentials through an HTTP API. This gives a session in response which will be used with all subsequent requests to get/edit data.

Comment: It is not very user friendly to have an already authenticated user (with salesforce) yet again ask to login (to your app). Rather it would be nicer if you set up single-sign-on where the salesforce login suffices to authenticate within your app and use salesforce as identity provider for instance. This though is a rather broad subject with many possibilities, so not really suited for a comment. And i'm not knowledgeable enough to make a quality answer about it.

Comment: I do not think that will be a possibility right now as that is up to organizational decisions. Could you help me on how to store the username and password and also use the session id in return?

Comment: Perhaps you should clarify what your app does, how it is intended to be used? There are plenty of options within salesforce.com to manage users without personally handling usernames or passwords. Who is the target audience of the app? Where is the app hosted? Which organization would they log into to get to your app? The devil is in the details.